# SSL AES128-GCM-SHA256 cipher vs RC4-MD5

Tags: tls

I'm performing a bandwidth performance test with a 2048 certificates using AES128-GCM-SHA256 cipher vs RC4-MD5.

Should I expect the AES128 cipher would actually outperform the RC4-MD5 cipher?

From my initials tests, I notice RC4-MD5 handling more bandwidth. I know RC4 is generally faster and requires less cpu processing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, AES should outperform RC4, if used on a CPU that has AESNI instructions. GCM is also fast, if used on a CPU with CLMUL instructions. On my laptop with an i7-6700HQ, `openssl speed -evp aes-128-gcm` with openssl 1.1.0e shows 5GB/sec on a single core running at 3.4GHz. Yes, really. I expect three times that performance  if all 4 cores are used (when all four cores are used, it runs at 2.6GHz, so you get 75% of that performance per core, but x4 the cores). The profiler shows the time is spent in a function called [_aesni_ctr32_ghash_6x](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/5c72e5ea7a9ce343e4cd595c3fc82956843185c8/crypto/modes/asm/aesni-gcm-x86_64.pl#L88).

RC4-MD5 are nowhere near that at 520MB/sec for rc4 and 670MB/sec for md5, which would be 0.29GB/sec combined.

Answer (score 2):

RC4 *[isn't secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Security)*. If security is a requirement, it should not be in contention, which makes its speed irrelevant. (To be honest, it's not black and white, and RC4 is still secure-*ish*. But it should be avoided if at all possible, and it should always be possible.)

If AES-GCM hardware acceleration is unavailable, *and* your secure software implementation has been found too slow for your purposes, modern TLS implementations (such as OpenSSL 1.1.0) support the [recently standardized](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7905) [ChaCha20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20)-[Poly1305](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly1305) cipher suites, which are more amenable to efficient and secure software implementations than AES or GCM.

Regardless, TLS cipher and MAC performance is not usually an issue for most purposes, even if you're using one of the slower options.